# Select distinct rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows:

```
id     fs_nature       Class   f_head
---------------------------------------
1      Monthly           II     1
2      Monthly           II     2
3      Quarterly         II     1
4      Quarterly         II     2
5      Quarterly         II     3
```

Using sql query i want to pick rows like

```
Monthly     II
Quarterly   II
```

Is it possible.If yes then please show the query as i am very confused .

Comment: `select distinct fs_nature, class from t`

Comment: Sorry for bothering you all with a stupid question.I admit i m a dumb

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
SELECT fs_nature, Class FROM table GROUP BY fs_nature, Class
```

or event faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fs_nature, Class FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Query will be like that :

```
SELECT DISTINCT fs_nature,Class FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct(fs_nature),class FROM table_name;

Comment: What are the parentheses for? In my opinion they only obfuscate the query.